# Get dashboard name using Dahing ruby framework

Tags: ruby, dashing

I'm using dashing to create some dashboards, but now I want to create for example 2 dashboards, basic job code is the same, only source differs, is there a way get name of the dashboard.

I've tried request.request_uri, but I'm getting exception that such variable does not exists.

Is there a way, maybe there is a way to pass that value throe dashboards files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good luck doing something like this by leveraging the **file** variable.

For instance:

```
env = File.basename(__FILE__, File.extname(__FILE__))
```

That'll give you the dashboard name in the env variable.